# Find what's crashing my phone

Tags: samsung, crashes, logging, hard-reset

I have a Galaxy M51. At times, when I wake up in the morning, the phone is dead - No response to any of the buttons, when I call it from another phone, it says "the number is switched off", no response on connecting charger. Only when I press power button and vol. down together (hard restart), does the phone turn on and then starts working perfectly normal, only to show a similar behaviour in a few days

Comment: It is difficult to guess if it is a hardware or a software problem. The only safe way to get an answer is to perform a factory reset and not installing all your commonly used apps. Instead use the phone plain for some days and check if the problem occurs again. If not re-install your apps one-by-one to find the app that causes this problem.

Comment: Is there no way to find the culprit other than factory data reset of the phone?